# Nested skipWhile in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have nested api requests and I splitted them like I would do it with Promises (.then) with the flatMap operator. So this works great but I have also to check if the response is valid and if not I would wait for the correct one, so I added the skipWhile operator.

```
init(): Observable<any> {
    return this.loadDataA();   
}    

loadDataA(): Observable<any> {

    return this._serviceA.loadData()
        .skipWhile((foo) => foo === undefined)
        .flatMap((foo) => this.loadDataB(foo.importantProp));
}

loadDataB(important: string): Observable <any> {

    return this._serviceB.loadData(important)
        .skipWhile((bar) => bar === undefined)
        .map((bar) => true);
}
```

The problem is that the the first skipWhile in function loadDataA works like it should, it does not go into flatMap if the response is undefined. The skipWhile operator in loadDataB does not go into .map but it returns to flatmap of loadDataA so that it never executes .map in loadDataB function. So how can I perform a nested skipWhile behaviour? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your `_serviceA.loadData()` looks like, but I have a strong suspicion that you are probably better of using the [`filter`-operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter):

```
loadDataA(): Observable<any> {
    return this._serviceA.loadData()
        .filter(foo => foo != null) // will not emit any data if it is null or undefined
        .flatMap(foo => this.loadDataB(foo.importantProp));
}

loadDataB(important: string): Observable <any> {
    return this._serviceB.loadData(important)
        .filter(bar => bar != null)
        .mapTo(true);
}
```

Comment: The problem with the filter operator is that, it would filter the undefined response but i will not receive the valid one in the stream. With skipWhile i would skip the responses until the valid one receives.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you just said - maybe you can draw a stream-diagram for your case - but a filter has no influence on what data it will receive - it will receive all data that is emitted from its source, it will just omit certain data.